Wald test with permutation standard error?
Many statistical tests are based on a Wald-like z-statistic: $z = \frac{\hat{\theta} - \theta_0}{\text{SE}(\hat{\theta})}$ where $\theta$ is the parameter of interest, $\theta_0$ is the value under the null hypothesis, and SE is the standard error. Then a pvalue can be calculated by comparing $z$ to a standard Normal(0,1) distribution.
I'm wondering if it is okay to estimate the standard error in a z-test based on a permutation null distribution of $\theta$? Or should the standard error for a z-test always be calculated under the alternative hypothesis?
More context:
I know I can directly calculate a pvalue from the permutation distribution, but in my case, I'm trying to do a meta-analysis which requires a point estimate and standard error from each cohort. However, there is no closed form standard error estimate for the statistic I'm using, but I already have a permutation null distribution of the statistic.  Can I just use the standard error of the permutation distribution for the meta analysis?
The statistic I'm using is the "normalized enrichment score" (NES) from GSEA.  The NES does not have a standard error formula and a permutation test is used to calculate its pvalue.  I'm wondering if can use the standard deviation of the permutation distribution as my standard error estimator for meta analysis.
EDIT: this answer seems to suggest that it is okay to estimate the standard error under the permutation null distribution, but I am not sure.

The score test (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Score_test), also known as the Rao test and the Lagrange Multiplier test, evaluates the statistic at the null hypothesis, writing loosely.  It is asymptotically equivalent to the Wald test and the likelihood ratio test; in small samples, any of the three can be superior.

@jbowman: to me that suggests it would be okay to use the permutation standard error in the wald test, but I'm not sure.  What do you think?

Yes, it does, although it then becomes similar to a score test instead of a Wald test, to be a little pedantic about it.
